# Unable to install JST Server Adapters in Eclipse from 2021-12 - https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-12/

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server, integration, jst

Unable to install JST Server Adapters in Eclipse from 2021-12 - https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-12/ - An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_NEWWORLD_eclipse_java-2021-12_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
Public key not found for 810cecf8ba271008.
goes like that many times and i amunable to install Server Apache plugin to integrate  in eclipse IDE?

tried to install JST Server Adapters in Eclipse from 2021-12 - https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-12/

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: Are you *running* the 2021-12 release?